# Spring Data Rest Stream closed after Post

Tags: spring, angular, spring-boot

I'm using Spring Data Rest for my backend operations and Angular 2 for my frontend.

When I'm saving data using post method, it managed to save the data, but it can't return it in JSON format due to the following error

`"Could not read JSON document: Stream closed; nested exception is java.io.IOException: Stream closed"`

Here is the return body

```
{
    "created" : "2017-07-15T02:55:06.080+0000",
    "updated" : "2017-07-15T02:55:06.080+0000",
    "deleted" : null,
    "view_count" : 0,
    "status" : "active",
    "name" : "Howdy",
    "email" : "example@gmail.com",
    "phone" : null,
    "uid" : "JKHLJK78587JK6S",
    "last_login" : "2017-07-15T02:55:06.080+0000",
    "_links" : {
        "self" : {
            "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/users/11"
        },
        "user" : {
            "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/users/11"
        },
        "things" : {
        "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/users/11/things"
        }
    }
}, {
    "cause":{
        "cause":null,
        "message":"Stream closed"
    },
    "message":"Could not read JSON document: Stream closed; nested exception is java.io.IOException: Stream closed"
}
```

Comment: Could you add the stacktrace?